# Shading issue with holes and n-gons

Tags: topology, retopology

i made this model using the knife project tool for the holes. Way too late i notices that the n-gon faces give my shading issues. Would it have been the best solution to make them quads directly after applying the knife project? Now i dont really know where to start to connect all the holes so i have quads. I just added some edges with the knife tool but it doesnt fix all the issues. Smooth shading already fixes some, but also not all.

Whats the best approach to clean this up or how should i have done this after the knife project?

Thanks for your answers!
[image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition that works better:

[image]

You can work with quads as much as possible, or make sure that your ngons are not adjacent with faces that are not co-planar so that Blender doesn't try to smooth between this ngon and this other face.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, everything i tried like this made it even worse.  All the other ngons in the mesh aro ok, for example the ones in the middle, just the ones around the screw wont look good.

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/42eddd0a799c4e91ab7fed14fb3e47bc

Comment: yes what I show is not enough in your case because actually even though the ngons are flat surfaces it tries to smooth between the flat surface and the bevel, which gives these artefacts, I guess you can't avoid a good topology, like less edges for your round hole, quads, etc, also do you plan to use a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: Ok, no i dont need a subdicision surface modifier. I was pretty happy with the result, just had these little artifacts. So i will probably start again and pay more attention to the topology. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: you don't need or you must not use a Subdivision Surface? If you must not use, just create a topology similar as the one I use in y answer, except you have more edges

Comment: Actually i also want to learn how to model with good topology, but using the knife tool i dont make much progress. I think i have to try it again with a more low poly mesh.

Comment: @Hennes I'd not say ngons there are flat (planar) since making them flat (scaling to 0 by z) kinda makes it better. In this case proper topology is not even needed https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOmTC.jpg since one can workaround that. So make flat whatever needs to be flat there and it can be called a day. Dirty, not "nice", but working solution. Using Weighted Normal modifier can be next step in managing that, albeit not necessary here

Comment: I cant get the same result as you. What did you scale, the planes or the edge around the hole?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you were talking to me, Zak scaled both the flat surface and the very next faces (beginning of the bevel) so that they are co-planar, and it doesn't try to create any smoothness

Comment: I got it. Thank you both, im quite happy with that now!